# Vaadin problems with SEO

Tags: java, gwt, web, vaadin

I'm considering using Vaadin to develop one of my projects, however, from what I've read it seems this framework has some problems with SEO. Knowing that the main focus of Vaadin is to develop webapps, this wouldn't be much of a problem but the project I'll be developing is more of a community public website, in this case having problems with SEO would be a heavy burden.

My question is, does Vaadin really have this kind of problem ? If so, is there a way to go around it ?

I want to make sure that this website is currectly indexed for search engines, making a good website but it never appearing on related searches is pretty bad.

EDIT: I'm planning to use CustomLayout in HTML made by my designer on a good part of this website, would this change something regarding this problem ?

Comment: Be more specific about "SEO", it's a loaded term. What is it you need to accomplish / output?

Comment: I'm sorry it might be confusing but I've never had to worry about this kind of stuff before, it's been a long time since i had to work on this kind of web project.... I want to make sure that this website is currectly indexed for search engines, making a good website but it never appearing on related searches is pretty bad.

Comment: You might want to look at Wicket for your project. It doesn't come with a bunch of pretty built-in components, but it's a framework in the same vein, and gives you a great of control over HTML, bookmarks, and what's done using AJAX and what uses page reloads.

Comment: That said, I believe the important thing in making your site indexable is shoving your content at search engines. I.e. make it possible to get to all your content through regular links without using Javascript/AJAX. (And, obviously, having interesting content.) To what degree this is possible in Vaadin is something that you should be able to research. (As you should to find out how to do SEO, instead of going off vague buzzwords.)

Comment: For Vaadin, this might be interesting: https://vaadin.com/wiki/-/wiki/Main/Creating%20a%20bookmarkable%20application%20with%20back%20button%20support

Comment: Ok, thank you for these ideas, I'll keep on researching :)

Comment: In my opinion it's a very bad idea to use any server side component based framework for a website that is going to be accessed from outer world. Especially Vaadin, that has lots of issues with css customisation, as any generated html. It's place is within inner organisation systems like writing your own CRM.

Comment: That's pretty much what I've been reading about the uses of Vaadin. Thanks for your insight ! For internal application's however,it's really good :)

Comment: I would not say it's a bad choice for outer world access in general. If you wish to make an internet application accessible for the public Vaadin is a ok choice for framework. On the other hand if you want a page based website, then there are probably better alternatives.

Answer (score 0):

The answer might be in a deeper layer of Vaadin at GWT with some examples at:

http://www.infoq.com/resource/articles/progwt/en/resources/progwt.pdf